# Error while running node.js code in AWS-Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am getting following error while running code in AWS-Lambda.

> TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:447:11) at EventEmitter. (/var/task/index.js:52:13) at emitOne (events.js:77:13) at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:169:7) at exports.handler.eventEmitter.on.offset (/var/task/index.js:57:18)

```
'use strict';
let https = require('https');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var ratesData =[];
    var totalRecords =0;
    var events = require('events');
    var options = {
        hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/',
        method: 'GET'
    };
    // Create an eventEmitter object
    var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
    eventEmitter.on('getJson', function(offset)
    {    
        const req = https.request(options.toString(), (res) => {
            let body = '';
            console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
            console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
                // If we know it's JSON, parse it
                if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json')    
                {
                    var  requestedJson = JSON.parse(body);
                    body = requestedJson.records;

                    totalRecords = requestedJson.total_records;
                    body.forEach(function(record)
                    {
                        ratesData.push(record);
                    });
                }

                callback(null, body);
            });
        });
        req.on('error', callback);
        req.write(JSON.stringify(event.data));
        req.end();
    });
    console.log('in calling');
    // Bind the connection event with the handler
    eventEmitter.emit('getJson',0);
    for(var i=1;i < (totalRecords/100)+1;i++)
    {
        eventEmitter.emit('getJson',i);
    }
    console.log(ratesData);

};
```

Answer (score -1):

For one you have `toString()` on your options object. Remove that.

I'd also recommend testing locally as it's easier to debug.

```
// filename: test.js - run as node test.js

// Require your lambda 
require('./index.js');

// Dummy context
var context = { };

// The event object - make sure of its format. S3 buckets pass a Records array for example
var e = { };

// Call the Lambda function
lambda.handler(e, context, function(err, result) {
    console.log('------------');
    console.log('Context done');
    console.log('   error:', err);
    console.log('   result:', result);
  });
```